# Using node.js and Jade but index.jade isn't showing up

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using node.js and Jade, and I have index.jade in my public/views folder, however it's not showing up when I run the server and go to the page, even though everything is OK, there are no errors, and it should render. This is the code in the server.js :

```
console.log("Hello, world!");

var express = require("express")
  , app = express()
  , http = require("http").createServer(app);

app.set("ipaddr", "192.168.0.103");

app.set("port", 8080);

app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");

app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(express.static("public", __dirname + "/public"));

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get("/", function(request, response) {

  response.send("Server is up and running");

  response.render("index");

});

http.listen(app.get("port"), app.get("ipaddr"), function() {
  console.log("Server up and running. Go to http://" + app.get("ipaddr") + ":" + app.get("port"));


});
```

And this is my index.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')    
    title Super Awesome Chatroom
  body
    h1 Super Awesome Chatroom
    div
      div.inlineBlock
        span Your name:
          input(type="text", value="Anonymous")#name
        br
        form#messageForm
          textarea(rows="4", cols="50", placeholder="Share something!", maxlength=200)#outgoingMessage
          input(type="button", value="Share", disabled=true)#send
      div.inlineBlock.topAligned
        b Participants
        br
        div#participants
    div#messages
```

Everthing should run properly, when I go to xxx.xxx.xxx:8080, it just shows "Server is up and running", but isn't showing the index.jade. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you have forgotten to include the `router` middleware. Also, in your route handler you are returning two responses. If you simply want to render the index view, remove the response.send():

```
var express = require("express")
  , app = express()
  , http = require("http").createServer(app);

app.set("ipaddr", "192.168.0.103");

app.set("port", 8080);

app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");

app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static("public", __dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(request, response) {

  response.render("index");

});

http.listen(app.get("port"), app.get("ipaddr"), function() {
  console.log("Server up and running. Go to http://" + app.get("ipaddr") + ":" + app.get("port"));


});
```

Also, always keep in mind this very important fact about express: **the order in which you define your middleware is critical!** That is why I moved the `static` middleware after `router` in order to give priority to `router`, since this is the middleware that handles the route callbacks which you define in your application.